# How to rewrite HTML in to PHP echoes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to split my last post into more sections.

I am working with AJAX & Database. The goal is to a have a clickable division (button) in a view. When this div is clicked the AJAX query is called and retrieves 5 movies from my DB and displays them in the view. What I am struggling the most with, is how to style the newly retrieved array, that I am displaying with jquery in the original division.

I am trying to follow [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) *w3schools* tutorial. I am trying to rework my original styling according to how it is done in the tutorial. But **I do not know how to write all the opening tags with their attributes into the echoes**.

So if anyone here would be so kind and could show me how to rewrite at least few of them I would really appreciate it. All the lines starting with the comment `<!--fix-->` are those I need to rewrite.

**EDIT ----------------------------------------------------**

The problem is that I have a CI view page. On that page is a division with content. I am trying to replace this content with new content retrieved using the xmlhttp request. The request calls a file that establishes connection with my DB, runs the query, stores the result in an array and then echoes back the result already split and styled using the while loop. Below is the content of the file called by the jquery request.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','obs2');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"obs2");
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id > 5";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
        <a style="display:block" href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>">
            <div id="suggested" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <div id="info">
                    <div id="info_center">
                        <p><b><?php echo $row->name ?></b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mosaic-block fade">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>" class="mosaic-overlay">

                    <div class="details">
                        <p><?php echo $row->summary ?></p>
                    </div>
                    </a>

                    <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://puu.sh/5DSWj.jpg"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="info">
                    <div id="info_center">
                        <p>Rating: 7.7</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>    

  }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

So from what I understand from the tutorial is that I need to be echoing each of the lines in inside the while loop. And what I do not know is how to rewrite all the tags and the php echoes that are already in there. I hope this makes it more clear.

**----------------------------------------------------**

**original code**

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($pages->result() as $row): ?>
    <a style="display:block" href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>">
      <div id="suggested" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div id="info">
          <div id="info_center">
            <p><b><?php echo $row->name ?></b></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mosaic-block fade">
          <a href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>" class="mosaic-overlay">

            <div class="details">
              <p><?php echo $row->summary ?></p>
            </div>
          </a>

          <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://puu.sh/5DSWj.jpg"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="info">
          <div id="info_center">
            <p>Rating: 7.7</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>    
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

**according to this**

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

**progress**

```
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
<!--fix--><a style="display:block" href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>">
<!--fix--><div id="suggested" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
<!--fix-->  <div id="info">
<!--fix-->    <div id="info_center">
                echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";
              echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";

<!--fix-->  <div class="mosaic-block fade">
<!--fix-->    <a href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>" class="mosaic-overlay">

<!--fix-->      <div class="details">
                  echo "<p>" . $row['summary'] . "</p>";
                echo "</div>";
              echo "</a>";

<!--fix-->    <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://puu.sh/5DSWj.jpg"></div>
            echo "</div>";

<!--fix-->  <div id="info">
<!--fix-->    <div id="info_center">
<!--fix-->      <p>Rating: 7.7</p>
              echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
          echo "</div>";
        echo "</a>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I think your original code is cleaner and easier to maintain. Just because w3schools suggests it doesn't mean it is best practice. *Many times the opposite is true.*

Comment: Oh God please no, don't put all the lines in echos, just output the HTML and use `<?= ?>` echo tags to output the variables, or worst case use heredoc.

Comment: wait what?! it does not have to be each line = 1 echo? Can you PLEASE send me in what I should then enclose the whole code? And in what do I put the original php echoes? I am sorry for not getting this :/ Should it be inside the while loop? `while(){<?= ORIGINAL CODE ?>}` ??

Comment: In regard to the post that got deleted -> There are changes to the original code. He closes php and then opens it again at the end. But What I don understand is how does the code between gets echoed into the result? Can you please clarify that **MikeF** ?? PLEASE?

Comment: @James If it's all inside of a php tag, then if you want something sent to the page, it must be echoed. I don't understand what you don't understand about that. all of your `<!--fix-->` lines need to be written the same way the non-`<!--fix-->` lines are.

Comment: @James. You were almost right. You just forgot the closing `?>` at the end of the loop initialization, which *is* there in the original code. I tried to address this in a little more detail in my answer.

Comment: @KevinB what I do not understand is how this `<a href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>" class="mosaic-overlay">` should look like when I start the line with echo. What do I enclose in what when there are the styles and other echoes..

Comment: you get rid of `<?php echo`. and use basic string concatenation, the same way you have on other lines.

Comment: @KevinB so like this `echo "<a href="base_url('core/detail/'.$row[id])" class="mosaic-overlay">";` ??

Comment: more like this: `echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";`, but i think even that can be simplified down to `echo "<p>$row['name']</p>";` iirc

Comment: @KevinB Wait. No you're loosing me again. You just told me to change this `echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";` into this `echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";` Which is the exact same thing. I was asking if this `<a href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>" class="mosaic-overlay">` should look like this `echo "<a href="base_url('core/detail/'.$row[id])" class="mosaic-overlay">";` Damn, why is this so complicated.

Comment: No... i'm saying look at `echo "<p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>";` to understand how you should change `<a href="<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>" class="mosaic-overlay">`. The only difference is you have to escape the inner double quotes.

Comment: @KevinB man, could you please, please, just show me?

Comment: I'd rather point you to the documentation for string concatenation than write an answer that shows you how to add one string to another. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: You're making it MUCH harder than it really is. echo needs a string. So, generate a string and pass it to it. `echo "Hello" . " World";` or `echo "Hello" . $somevar . " World"` the fact that your string contains html makes no difference.

Comment: @KevinB you were mentioning I should escape the inner double quotes. So should I make it like this: `echo "<a href = &quot;base_url(&quot;core/detail/" . $row[id] . "&quot; class=&quot;mosaic-overlay&quot;>"` ??

Answer (score 1):

Don't follow the convention used in that tutorial. Not only can't you trust everything W3schools says (they even say that in their disclaimer), but it's just less readable. Especially when you have a propert editor, you can benefit from code highlighting in your HTML. That will be gone if you echo all your html. Apart from that you just clutter your code, and you have to escape every quote. Long story short: don't do that. :)

Regarding the echos of the values inside the html, you can shorten this:

```
<?php echo base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>
```

to this:

```
<?=base_url('core/detail/'.$row->id) ?>
```

`<?=` is just a shorthand. I think it even works when the short opening tag (`<?`) is disabled, but if you want your code to be independent of that setting you should verify that.

Also, though I prefer the `{ .. }` style of blocks, I think using `: ... endforeach` is much clearer when combined with HTML. So I wouldn't change that either.

If you do want to change it anyway, you will still need the PHP closing tag, which you have forgotten now. So:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
```

becomes:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ ?>
```

Of course you can put `{ ?>` or only the `{` on the same line as the `while` statement, if you like.

[edit]
Regarding your comment: Everything outside PHP tags gets outputted as-is. So the code:

```
Hello <?php echo 'lovely'; ?> world <?php /* More code without output*/ ?>
```

results in the phrase:

```
Hello lovely world
```

So as you can see, it is often much easier to put large chunks of plain text/html outside of PHP tags, and only briefly open and close PHP tags to echo some variable content.

Comment: I am just gonna repost my previous comment.It is not working because I need to echo the code. The code is stored in a php file. If you take a look at the tutorial it would be the `getuser.php` file that is called with the `xhmlhttp`. In the file I have the database connection, the query that is ran against the db and stored in the `$result` and the actual styling of each row returned by the query is in the `while` loop. Which means I have to echo it so it can be returned by he xmlhttp request and displayed inside the `txtHint` division just like in the tutorial. Do you get my point?

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is the CORRECT way to do it. The w3schools version is completely wrong and you should avoid that.

Everyone would be better able to assist you if you try to describe what is NOT working with your original code.

Comment: It is not working because I need to echo the code. The code is stored in a php file. If you take a look at the tutorial it would be the `getuser.php` file that is called with the `xhmlhttp`. In the file I have the database connection, the query that is ran against the db and stored in the `$result` and the actual styling of each row returned by the query is in the `while` loop. Which means I have to echo it so it can be returned by he xmlhttp request and displayed inside the `txtHint` division just like in the tutorial. Do you get my point?

Comment: @James *"because I need to echo the code"* why do you need to echo it. Looking at the tutorial doesn't indicate any reason why you can't do it the way you did in the original.

Comment: The way PHP works, it should output the HTML just fine, without the ECHO statements. Placing an "echo" statement in front of each line will essentially do the same thing. That is why everyone is wondering why you need to have "echo"? Is it not outputting those HTML tags (e.g. <a>, <div> etc.)

Comment: Then explain to me why nothing happens when I click on the `next_btn`... Obviously something is wrong somewhere